# Use Swift Playground with BLE and HM-10

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ipad-playgrounds

I’m currently trying to build a swift playground that can communicate with a HM-18 BLE module.

I’m new to swift. I just don’t get the delegate thing and what objects I need to assign there (???).

Let me break down one line and explain what parts I think I understand:

`let managerDelegate: PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManagerDelegate = ???`

**Let declares** a constant with the **name managerDelegate** which must be of **type PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManagerDelegate**

I just have no idea what comes after the =

This is my code so far:

```
import CoreBluetooth
import PlaygroundBluetooth
import PlaygroundSupport

// Create State enum (shape)
enum Shape: String, CaseIterable {
    case on, off
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Get all cases
    let LEDStates = Shape.allCases
    
    // State Variable (state binding observables -> learn)
    @State private var selectedStateIndex = 0
    
    // I dont get this part from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundbluetooth/connecting_to_bluetooth_peripherals_in_swift_playgrounds
    
    let managerDelegate: PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManagerDelegate = ???
    
    let manager = PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManager(services: nil)
    manager.delegate = managerDelegate
    
    
    let viewDelegate: PlaygroundBluetoothConnectionViewDelegate = ???
    let connectionView = PlaygroundBluetoothConnectionView(centralManager: manager, delegate: viewDelegate)
    connectionView.dataSource = viewDelegate
    
    // Place the connection view within the rest of your page's content.
    let page: UIViewController & PlaygroundLiveViewSafeAreaContainer = ???
    page.view.addSubview(connectionView)
    
    // Position the connection view in the top right corner.
    connectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: page.liveViewSafeAreaGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    connectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: page.liveViewSafeAreaGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    
    // This I understand 
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = page
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            
            Picker("LED State", selection: $selectedStateIndex) {
                ForEach(0..<LEDStates.count) { index in
                    Text(self.LEDStates[index].rawValue).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: You need to declare a class that conforms to `PlaygroundBluetoothCentralMananagerDelegate` and assign an instance of that class.

Comment: Where do I have to declare it? And what has to go inside the class?

Comment: Create the class in your playground. The protocol is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundbluetooth/playgroundbluetoothcentralmanagerdelegate). Your class needs to implement the functions that you need to handle the Bluetooth events.

Comment: Okay I got this BluetoothSerial class from GitHub https://github.com/hoiberg/swiftBluetoothSerial and I think this is what you mean, right?

Comment: You can work from that; It is built for CoreBluetooth; You would need to modify it to work with Playground bluetooth

Comment: Is it okay to have it in a different module? I have my main code in the page module. What tutorial or keyword would you recommend to learn about this stuff in the first place?

Comment: You can put it in a different module.I have never used Bluetooth in a playground, but it is very similar to Core Bluetooth, so searching for that should get you started

Comment: Okay if I declare a managerDelegate to be a CBCentralManagerDelegate, do I need to give it a value? Like this:

Comment: let managerDelegate: CBCentralManagerDelegate = something

Comment: You won’t use `CBCentralManagerDelegate` because you are in a playground so you need to use the playground equivalent, so `managerDelegate = YourDelegateClass()`

Comment: This drives me literal crazy I’m stuck here since 3 days and I just can’t find any tutorials. I’ve watched 20 hours swift tutorials so I know how to declare a variable or how to use control flow FOR DAYS. But I just don’t get this. WTF IM SO MAD RN

Comment: Thank you so much for your help though I feel like such a fool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217079/discussion-between-larsinka-and-paulw11).